# Не подключается к mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Почему php не подключается к mysql, вот код:

```
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'publications';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'pass';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Невозможно подключиться к MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
  or die("Невозможно выбрать базу данных: " . mysql_error());
```

Ошибку не выдает, но и выбрать ничего не получается. К примеру если изменить значение`$db_username` на `root2`, то ничего не изменится

Comment: какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: В том и дело, что ошибки никакой, но и подключения тоже нет. Я рассчитывал что при подключение с неверными данными, ошибку отобразится на странице браузера

Comment: @MishaSpring, функции `mysql_` устарели начиная с 5.5.0 PHP.

Comment: Да используйте лучше mysqli_

Comment: Не может быть так, что у вас отключен вывод сообщений об ошибках в браузер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующие.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```